# how to skip elements in php array list

Tags: php, phpseclib

I am using php's net_ssh2 module to login to servers and retrieve a file for real time data collection. The servers all have the same username and password. The problem I am facing is, if one of the server is down or has a different password for some reason, my script stops. I need script to skip the problematic server and continue to process other servers in the array.

Here is my current php script to do this:

```
include('Net/SSH2.php');
$servers=array('server1', 'server2','server3', 'server4', 'server5');
foreach ($servers as &$value1) {

    $server=$value1."example.net";

    $ssh = new Net_SSH2($server);
        if (!$ssh->login('username', 'password')) {
            exit('Login Failed');
        }
```

How would I skip the servers in the servers array that I am not able to connect and continue processing the others?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [**`continue`**](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php):

> **continue** is used within looping structures to skip the rest of the current loop iteration and continue execution at the condition evaluation and then the beginning of the next iteration.

```
if (!$ssh->login('username', 'password')) {
    echo('Login Failed'); // <-- remove if desired
    continue;
}
```

If you want your loop to end when you find a successful server connection you would use [**`break`**](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php), too:

```
if (!$ssh->login('username', 'password')) {
    continue;
}
else {
    break;
}
```